# ¿Como capturar la excepcion que genera un controlador?

Tags: c#, ajax, mvc

Tengo el siguiente código que genera un reporte en PDF:

```
public void reporte(int ID)
{

            try{

            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet("Hoja_Salida");
            DataTable dtEmpresa = Empresa.Obtener(Convert.ToInt32(SessionManager.Item(SessionItems.fkEmpresa)));
            DataTable dtHojaSalida = DocumentoDetalle.ObtenerReporteHojaSalida(ID);



            dtEmpresa.TableName = "Encabezado";
            dtHojaSalida.TableName = "Detalle";

            ds.Tables.Add(dtEmpresa.Copy());
            ds.Tables.Add(dtHojaSalida.Copy());

            ds.Tables["Encabezado"].Columns.Remove("logo");
            ds.Tables["Encabezado"].Columns.Add("logo",Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"));



            Reportes.Reportepdf rp = new Reportes.Reportepdf();
            rp.SetDataSource(ds);

            BinaryReader stream = new BinaryReader(rp.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat));
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Reporte.pdf");
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", stream.BaseStream.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(stream.BaseStream.Length)));
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close();
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                 throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
}
```

y lo ejecuto desde la vista de la siguiente forma:

```
 @{if(item.Folio != null){ <li><a href="@Url.Action("reporte", new { IDD= @item.ID})" class="fa fa-print">Hoja de salida sin costos</a></li> } else{}}
```

Alguien me puede dar una idea de como cachar la excepción y mandarla a la vista,
para poder mandarla a otro controlador a través de ajax.

Comment: Hola mvega :) una pregunta, ¿por qué requieres enviar la excpeción a otro `View` para que a su vez se envíe a otro `Controller`? Mi pregunta va enfocada a ¿por qué no enviarlo directamente a otro `Controller` mediante el método `RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");`

Comment: hola y muchas gracias por tu tiempo, estoy intentado llamar el action name como lo mencionaste pero no se ejecuta , estoy haciendo esto  catch (Exception ex)
            {
                RedirectToAction("Error", "Home" ,new{ URL= Request.Url.AbsolutePath, Error = ex.Message});   
            }

Comment: Publiqué una respuesta que a mi modo personal de programar me parece una forma mejor de manejar la excepción y lograr el objetivo de guardarla en la base de datos y mostrarla en pantalla. Espero que te funcione :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de solucionar el problema que presentas es agregando el contenido de la excepción a una variable de sesión con `Session["NombreDeLaVariableDeSesion"]`:

```
public void reporte(int ID)
{
    try
    {
        //Código de tu reporte
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         HttpContext.Session["ExcepcionEnReporte"] = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Luego, en la vista donde se invocó el reporte, si se generó una excepción redireccionamos a un `Controller`:

```
@{
    if(item.Folio != null)
    { 
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("reporte", new { IDD= @item.ID})" class="fa fa-print">Hoja de salida sin costos</a></li>

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["ExcepcionEnReporte"].ToString())){
            RedirectToAction("ShowException", "Exception");
        }
    } 
    else { }
}
```

Ahora, en el `ExceptionController`, leemos la variable de sesión, la guardamos en la base de datos y luego direccionamos a la Vista para mostrar el mensaje de error:

```
public class ExceptionController : Controller
{
    public string ExceptionMessage = string.empty;

    public ActionResult ShowException()
    {
        ExceptionMessage = HttpContext.Session["ExcepcionEnReporte"] != null ? HttpContext.Session["ExcepcionEnReporte"].ToString() : string.Empty;

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ExceptionMessage))
            //Guardado de la excepción en la base de datos

        //Guardamos el contenido de la excepción para luego mostrarla en la vista
        ViewBag.SpanExceptionMessage = ExceptionMessage;

        //Regresas un View para que se muestre el mensaje del error
        return View();
    }
}
```

Por último, solo mostramos el mensaje en la vista utilizando un `<span>`:

```
<span class="help-block">@ViewBag.SpanExceptionMessage</span>
```