# ¿Cómo obtener el error en alert de la vista para manejarlo en el Controller en C#? ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

En la vista tengo la siguiente función para retornar un archivo adjunto:

```
 $("#export").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var url = "/Libro/GeneraDoc";
     window.location.href = url;
  });
```

En el `Controller`:

```
public ActionResult GeneraDoc()
{
    try
    {
        .....
        .....
        genera_reporte(parametro1,parametro2,...);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        String e=error.Message.ToString();
    }
}

public ActionResult genera_reporte(parametro1,parametro2,...)
{
    LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
    report.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/" + nombreReporte);
    report.DataSources.Clear();
    report.EnableExternalImages = true;
    ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 = new ReportDataSource();
    ReportDataSource reportDataSource2 = new ReportDataSource();
    reportDataSource1.Value = query1;
    reportDataSource1.Name = nombreDataSource1;
    reportDataSource2.Value = query2;
    reportDataSource2.Name = nombreDataSource2;
    report.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
    report.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource2);
    report.SetParameters(parametro);
    report.Refresh();

    String mimeType;
    String encoding;
    String filenameExtension;
    String[] streamIds;
    Warning[] warnings;

    FileContentResult fileContentResult = new FileContentResult(report.Render(format, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamIds, out warnings), mimeType);
    fileContentResult.FileDownloadName = Path.ChangeExtension(fileDownloadName, filenameExtension);

    string[] streams;
    byte[] renderedBytes = report.Render(format, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamIds, out warnings);

    String filePath = Server.MapPath("~/ruta/" + "/" + fileDownloadName + "." + "pdf");
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
    fs.Write(renderedBytes, 0, renderedBytes.Length);
    fs.Close();              

    return fileContentResult;
}
```

Mi pregunta es, en caso de error, quisiera saber cómo obtengo el mensaje del error en un `alert` dentro de la vista, específicamente dentro de

```
$("#export").click(function (e) {.....
```

Una solución sería hacerlo mediante ajax:

```
   $("#export").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            fd.append("numero_interno", $("#numero_interno).val());
            fd.append("numero", $("#numero).val());
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Libro/GeneraDoc/',
                data: fd,
                DataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    //window.location.href = url;
                    if (data == 1) {
                        mostrar_msj_success('Doc generado exitosamente');
                    } else if (data == 2) {
                        mostrar_msj_error("No se pudo ingresa XML a la base de datos");
                    } else if (data == 3) {
                        mostrar_msj_error("El documento no es de tipo electronico");

                    } else {
                        mostrar_msj_error(data);
                    }

                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    mostrar_msj_error("Error de conección al generar doc");

                }
            });

        });
```

pero no descarga documentos, ya que tengo entendido que cuando son de tipo retorno file, no hay soporte para ajax. Al menos que exista algún truco que se pueda abrir un como archivo para descargar el documento que ya este guardado.

Comment: Hola Danilo, hace unos días respondí una [pregunta muy parecida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46450/16841) justo es como cachar la excepción en el `Controller` y manejar el mensaje del lado de la vista, espero que te pueda servir, y si no te funciona revisamos la forma de acuerdo a tu problema

Comment: gracias por responder @Flxtr , pero no me sirve esta respuesta, ya que lo que necesito, es obtener el error en un alert de javascritp que esta definido en la vista, especificamente en el evento click de $("#export").click(function (e) {..  como dije antes.

Comment: no es una pregunta duplicada

Comment: Bien, entonces el tema se centra en la función `$("#export").click(function (e) {...` ahí dentro debes poner un `ajax` para hacer la petición a la URL y ya sea que en `success` o en el `failure` manejes el error de la excepción, eso solucionaría totalmente lo que necesitas

Comment: si, entiendo @Flxtr, pero el problema que es utilizo la funcion genera_reporte, que se encargar de abrir un documento para descargarse, lo cual no funciona con ajax, al menos que llame dos veces al metodo GeneraDoc, una vez por ajax, verificando si está correcto, y si lo está, llamar otra vez al metodo GeneraDoc de esta forma var url = "/Libro/GeneraDoc";
     window.location.href = url;
pero no sería eficiente, ya que estaría al metodo 2 veces, no se si me entiendes.

Comment: Sí, lo comprendo, lo que no sé es porqué el archivo que deseas descargar no funciona por medio de `ajax`, ¿existe alguna razón en especial?

Comment: @Flxtr edite la pregunta, mostrando como lo hago con ajax. Pero tengo entendido, que cuando retorna desde el controller tipo file, no funciona con ajax, ademas que lo he probado, al menos que exista algún truco o forma.

Comment: Bien, tu pregunta ya tiene 3 votos de reapertura, echemos un vistazo a tu código :)

Comment: ok, quizas una solución para obtener el error que indica el controller, es hacer algun return content, o en el mismo evento click, hacer algo como esto:

try {
                    window.location.href = url;
                }catch (e){
                    alert(e.menssaje);
                }

pero como sería?

Comment: alguna idea para solución??

Comment: Sí, dame unos minutos y publico una posible solución a tu problema, sin embargo, no podré replicar tu escenario y solo pondré partes muy concretas de código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este caso, propongo un escenario un poco diferente. Primero, siguiendo la lógica de tu código, se ejecutará la primer llamada `ajax`, llegará al `LibroController`, acción `GeneraDoc`, pero ahora en este método, simplemente guardaremos el archivo temporalmente en el servidor (esto nos funcionará más adelante), posteriormente, solo regresaremos la ruta del archivo para que con la segunda llamada `ajax` obtengamos el resultado deseado:

```
$("#export").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fd.append("numero_interno", $("#numero_interno).val());
    fd.append(" numero ", $(" # numero).val());
    $.ajax({
        async : false,
        type : "POST",
        url : '/Libro/GeneraDoc/',
        data : fd,
        DataType : 'json',
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        success : function (filename) {
            window.location = '/Libro/BuscarArchivo?file=' + filename;
        },
        error : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            mostrar_msj_error("Error de conección al generar doc");
        }
    });
});
```

El `Controller` te regresará la ruta del archivo guardado, si la petición se completó correctamente se realizará una redirección a una URL que finalmente es un `Controller`, donde ahí sí podrás abrir el archivo deseado:

```
public ActionResult GeneraDoc()
{
    try
    {
        return Content(genera_reporte(parametro1,parametro2,...));
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        return Content("Exception: " + ex.message);
    }
}

public string genera_reporte(parametro1,parametro2,...)
{
    //Aquí va la lógica y generación del reporte en disco
    string fileName = //Nombre y ruta del archivo guardado en disco
}
```

Entonces, si la primer petición se ejectó de forma correcta, se realizará la redirección a `window.location = '/Libro/BuscarArchivo?file=' + filename;` para que del lado del Controller quede de esta forma:

```
public ActionResult BuscarArchivo(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        //Lógica para buscar el archivo en el servidor con el filename recibido
        return fileContentResult;
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        return Content("Exception: " + ex.message);
    }
}
```

Obviamente, esto conlleva a tener una adecuada codificación y validaciones para no ir dejando archivos en el servidor, además de que recomendaría que una vez que se generó recupero o abrió el archivo en el navegador de forma correcta, se ejecute una tercer llamada enviando el `filename` para borrar el archivo que anteriormente se generó.

Comment: Me gusto tu idea, algo eso era lo que justo necesitaba, como no se me ocurrió antes. Te daría las gracias, pero no se puede dar las gracias por este foro. :)

Comment: Ya lo has hecho :)